# How can i get Plain text from Ajax Editor?

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to get both plain text as well as html text from Ajax Editor. I'm able to get the html text and not able to retrieve plain text. i'm not supposed to eliminate html tags from the editor to retrieve plain text.

Is there any property, which gives plain text from ajax editor?

Sample code from my app:

i'm able to get rich html text like this:
 string desc =  QuestionAndAnswerEditor.Content;

Same way i want plain text.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML.Encode for getting encoded text. and html.decode ..